Puedo usar un event listener con dos eventos?
Estoy haciendo una página de "pixel art", y no quiero que el "lápiz" dibuje cuando no estoy presionando el botón del mouse, intente hacer esto pero o puedo hacer que el "lápiz” funcione con el click o que funcione con el mouseover. En conclusión quiero hacer mousedown y seguir arrastrando el mouse para dibujar con el mousedown presionado.
Lo que está haciendo mi código ahora es funcionar con el mouseover sin necesidad del mousedown. Espero puedan ayudarme
Este es mi JS code:
const GRIDSIDE = 600;
let side = 16;

const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

for (let i = 0; i < (side * side); i++) {
    const gridElement = document.createElement("div");
    grid.appendChild(gridElement);

    gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
    gridElement.style.width = ${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px;
    gridElement.style.height = ${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px;

    gridElement.addEventListener("mousedown", addColor);
    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseover", addColor);     
}

function addColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

Mi HTML:
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Y mi CSS por si ayuda:
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;

    box-shadow: 10px 10px #D6EAF8;
}

.gridElement {
    flex: none;
    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}


Los eventos mousedown y mouseover, así como cualquier evento que comience con "mouse" pasa a la función callback un argumento del tipo MouseEvent, el cual cuenta con la propiedad buttons, cuyo valor será:

0: Cuando no hay un botón presionado
1: Botón primario presionado (generalmente el izquierdo)
2: Botón secundario presionado
4: Botón auxiliar presionado (el de la rueda)
8: 4to botón presionado (para mouse de 5 botones, el mismo que actua con la función atrás en el browser)
16: 5to botón presionado (para mouse de 5 botones, el mismo que actúa con la función adelante en el browser)

Notar que los números entregados son potencias de 2, esto es así porque funcionan como banderas (flags), es decir, es posible combinar los valores. Por ejemplo, al presionar los botones primario y secundario al mismo tiempo se obtiene el valor 3 (1+2)
Entonces, lo único que le falta a tu código es un if en la función addColor, además te recomiendo agregar un preventDefault() porque el tener presionado el botón y mover, es la misma acción que el drag, razón por la cual si no lo agregas hay veces que no pinta correctamente
function addColor(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.buttons === 1){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }  
}

Demo completo:


const GRIDSIDE = 600;
const side = 16;
const size = `${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px`


const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

for (let i = 0; i < (side * side); i++) {
    const gridElement = document.createElement("div");
    grid.appendChild(gridElement);
  
    gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
    gridElement.style.width = size;
    gridElement.style.height = size;
    gridElement.draggable = false;

    gridElement.addEventListener("mousedown",addColor);
    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseover", addColor);     
}



function addColor(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.buttons === 1){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }  
}
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;

    box-shadow: 10px 10px #D6EAF8;
}

.gridElement {
    flex: none;
    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
<div class="grid"></div>






const GRIDSIDE = 600;
let side = 16;
let mouseDown = false;

const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

for (let i = 0; i < (side * side); i++) {
    const gridElement = document.createElement("div");
    grid.appendChild(gridElement);

    gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
    gridElement.style.width = ${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px;
    gridElement.style.height = ${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px;

    gridElement.addEventListener("mousedown",function() {
        mouseDown = true;
    });
    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseover", addColor);  
    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseup",function() {
        mouseDown = false;
    });
    gridElement.addEventListener("click", addColor);  
}

function addColor(e) {
    if(e.type === "mouseover" && mouseDown == true || e.type === "click") {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;

    box-shadow: 10px 10px #D6EAF8;
}

.gridElement {
    flex: none;
    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



